# UIButton will not respond

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I'm currently working through Apple's Swift tutorial. In it, i am trying to make a custom button respond to  tap and in turn print to the console. It seems to not be responding at all to any taps, or at the very least will not print it's response to the console.

Code is below, if anymore is needed please let me know.

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIView {


//MARK: Initializaion

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // overrides it's superclass implementation of the initializer

super.init(coder: aDecoder)
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 44, height: 44))

button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
addSubview(button)


func intrensicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 240, height: 44)
}

}


//MARK:  Button Action



func ratingButtonTapped(button:UIButton) {
    print("will it print?")


}

}
```

Comment: Try this : `@IBAction func ratingButtonTapped(button:UIButton)`

Comment: If done like Mr.UB wrote, don't forget to connect button in storyboard with this line of code using CTRL drag.

Answer (score 0):

Please try .TouchUpInside instead of TouchDown

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```